# In QGIS can I make an index grid vector dataset for a folder of orthophot extents?

Tags: qgis, orthophoto, index

I have a folder of orthophotos and I need to make a lookup grid for all the photos showing the extent of coverage for each photo in the folder.  I want the attribute in the grid to have the filename (and ideally the path) of the photo the tile shows the extent for. How can i do this without tracing each photo's outline manually? I am also not a python scripter so hoping there is a geoprocess like LasTools' LasBoundaryPro which does what I want but does it for LiDAR files whereas i want to do it for rasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geoprocess "Tile Index" under "Raster Miscellanious" does exactly what i need.